# Set font size for set_table() in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

I have been lookiing for a way to set the font size of values in the table produced by *set_table()* in the Python package, **xlsxwriter**, and cannot find a way to do so. I created a column chart and have been trying to set the font size using the code below but nothing I have tried works.

```
chart.set_table({'show_keys': True,
'num_font': {'name': 'Arial', 'size': 9}, # This option does not work
'font': {'size': 9} # This option does not work
})
```

Has anyone had any luck setting the font size for the values in the table under a column chart? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That functionality now exists. The following works:

```
chart.set_table({'show_keys': True,'font':{'size':9}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying fonts in chart tables isn't currently supported.